# Query, complete animation before applying style

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have this animation. After the div is moved in to the left I want to add the class "straighten" but it's being added immediately so the transition is never seen.

Is it possible to add the class after the movement is complete?

```
$('li.current .imageblock').css({
    left: '-300px'
}).animate({
    left: '60%'
}, {
    duration: 500
}).addClass("straighten").delay(3500).animate({
    left: '100%'
}, {
    duration: 500
})
```

working example at http://www.tomatedesign.com/stothers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the 'complete' option for .animate()

```
$('li.current .imageblock').css({left:'-300px'}).animate({left:'60%'},{duration:500,complete:function(){

    $(this).addClass("straighten").delay(3500).animate({left:'100%'},{duration:500 });

    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks did the trick nicely - only have to discover why the CSS transition isn't behaving how I expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Victor's answer, but this will add the class in the callback of the first animation so I won't be called until the first animation is complete.

```
$('li.current .imageblock').css({left: '-300px'}).animate({left: '60%'}, 
{duration: 500}, function() {
    $(this).addClass("straighten").delay(3500).animate({left: '100%'}, 
    {duration: 500});
});
```